# Etymology of the term monilophyte

Tags: botany, terminology, taxonomy, etymology

I would like to know the origin of the term *Monilophyta*. I know it's from Kenrick and Crane, but where did they get monilo-? It's not in my enormous Liddell and Scott Greek dictionary, nor is there any word starting with ilo- or hilo- that seems at all likely. Is it from the Latin word "monile" meaning necklace?

This is driving me crazy.

Comment: The Division has its name from a cross section of the stem, are lobes of protoxilema which remember the look of a necklace

Answer (score 2):

[Phylogeny and evolution of ferns (monilophytes) with a focus on the early leptosporangiate divergences](http://www.amjbot.org/content/91/10/1582.full):

> The monilophytes (= Infradivision Moniliformopses, sensu Kenrick and Crane, 1997⇓) share a distinctive vasculature, having protoxylem confined to lobes of the xylem strand (Stein, 1993⇓), therefore the Latin *moniliformis* appellation for “necklace-like.”

Answer (score 2):

[***Monilophytes***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fern) = Leptosporangiate ferns, horsetails, whisk ferns, marattioid ferns, & ophioglossoid ferns.

According to [*A Dictionary of Entomology*](https://books.google.com/books?id=9IcmCeAjp6cC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=monil&f=false):

> Latin, ***monil*** = necklace

As for "*phyte*," I'll quote this [Source](http://www.affixes.org/p/-phyte.html):

> Greek, -***phyte*** = denoting a plant or plantlike organism

So it literally means "**necklace plants**. "

From [Rai & Graham (2010)](http://m.amjbot.org/content/97/9/1444.full.pdf) :

> The extant monilophytes (a name based on a “moniliform” or necklace-like stele thought to be ancestral in the group; Kenrick and Crane, 1997; Pryer et al., 2004)

Note : ***stele*** = the central core of the stem and root of a vascular plant, consisting of the vascular tissue (xylem and phloem) and associated supporting tissue.

In other words, the vasculature of all of these plants are arranged like a beaded necklace. This is further alluded to in [Pryer et al. (2004)](http://m.amjbot.org/content/91/10/1582.full.pdf) as quoted in @Kendall's [answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/42941/16866).

Comment: Note: not to be confused with ***Molino***- = "mill" [[Source](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/molino)]